# How to prove a $W=\{(x,y):3x+y=0\}$ is a subspace of $ R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I prove this vector $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (closed under addition and scalar multiplication) if I have the condition $3x+y=0$. Does this mean this vector already has the $0$ vector since $3x+y=0$, and every other addition is in $ \mathbb{R}$ or what's the correct way to work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, you need to show three things:

1) the zero vector $(0,0)$ is in $W$;

2) $v,w\in W\implies v+w\in W$;

3) $w\in W$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ implies that $\lambda w\in W$.

Here is a proof.

1) $3\cdot 0+0=0$ Hence, $(0,0)\in W$.

2) Suppose $w=(w_{1},w_{2})\in W$ and $v=(v_{1},v_{2})\in W$. Then, by definition, $3w_{1}+w_{2}=3v_{1}+v_{2}=0$. Hence, $3(w_{1}+v_{1})+(w_{2}+v_{2})=3w_{1}+w_{2}+3v_{1}+v_{2}=0$. Therefore, $w+v=(w_{1}+v_{1},w_{2}+v_{2})\in W$.

3) Suppose $w=(w_{1},w_{2})\in W$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\lambda w=(\lambda w_{1},\lambda w_{2})$ and $3\cdot\lambda w_{1}+\lambda w_{2}=\lambda(3 w_{1}+w_{2})=\lambda\cdot 0=0$, since $w\in W$.

Comment: So the way to solve this problem is to substitute the given condition when  $u,v\in W$ in addition and scalar multiplication ,and we can assume any number in the domain that can possibly give us the condition 3x+y=0

Answer (score 4):

**Easily**: It is the kernel of a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^1$, hence it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

**Harder**: Show by hand that this set is a linear space (it is trivial that it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

It has an identity: $(0, 0)$ satisfies the equation.

It's closed under addition: If $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are both solutions, then

$$3(x_1 + x_2) + (y_1 + y_2) = (3x_1 + y_1) + (3x_2 + y_2) = 0$$

so their sum is also a solution, hence in the subset.

It's closed under scalar multiplication: I leave this to you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec x_1=(x_1,y_1) \in W$ and $\vec x_2=(x_2,y_2) \in W$.  This means that:
$$
3x_1+y_1=0 \quad \mbox{and}\quad 3x_2+y_2=0
$$

now we have to prove that, $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have:

$$
(\vec x_1+\lambda \vec x_2) \in W
$$

and this means:
$$
3(x_1+\lambda x_2)+(y_1+\lambda y_2)=0
$$
that can be proved true simply reordering:
$$
3(x_1+\lambda x_2)+(y_1+\lambda y_2)=3x_1+y_1+\lambda(3x_2+y_2)=0+\lambda \cdot 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

You need $W$ to be non-empty, but as you say, the zero vector is clearly in $W$.

For $W$ to be a subspace, you also need that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. So take two (general) elements in $W$ and an arbitrary scalar $\lambda$ and check whether their sum and a scalar multiple are in $W$ as well.

The idea is simple, you just have to go through the trouble of introducing names and carefully checking the conditions.